# How to unrotate imageview in a container

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/blue">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/small_plane"
        android:id="@+id/plane"
        android:layout_below="@id/diagramcompass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/holdingvor"
        android:id="@+id/arrows"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/diagramcompass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/diagrammcompass"
        android:id="@+id/diagramcompass"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:text="rotate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

and I need a rotation, when I get results from a sensors,of the element with id `container` that allows the rotation of all elements. The problem is that I want that `diagramcompass` is fixed and I want that this imageview don't rotate.

For now I use this solution in code:

```
  layout.setRotation(i);
  imageView.setRotation(-i);
```

that cancel the rotation, but this solution moves the imageview in the layout and this is not fixed.

So there is a better way to do it?

Thanks